# Solution exception:Input parameter index [-1] too low for Component

Tags: c#, grasshopper

I am not sure why I am getting this error for the input parameter index being too low. I usually get this error when the DA.GetData call can't find an input.  I had it working just a second ago. This time the names of the inputs match the DA.GetData calls.

It would help if I could get a line number in Grasshopper where this error was.  I guess that would be a separate question though.

```
namespace MyProject1
{
    public class NormalDist : GH_Component
    {
        public NormalDist()
          : base("Normal Distribution", "NormalDist",
              "Generates a normal distribution of points.",
              "Extras", "Normal Distribution")
        {

        }


        protected override void 
RegisterInputParams(GH_Component.GH_InputParamManager pManager)
        {
            pManager.AddIntegerParameter("Seed", "Seed", "integer seed for 
random number generator", GH_ParamAccess.item);
            pManager.AddNumberParameter("StdDev", "StdDev", "Standard 
Deviation", GH_ParamAccess.item);
            pManager.AddNumberParameter("Mean", "Mean", "Mean of the normal 
distribution", GH_ParamAccess.item);
    }

     /// Registers all the output parameters for this component.

    protected override void 
RegisterOutputParams(GH_Component.GH_OutputParamManager pManager)
    {
        pManager.AddNumberParameter("Output", "output", "A collection of 
normally distributed points", GH_ParamAccess.item);

    }

    /// This is the method that actually does the work.

    protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
    {

        int seed = 0;
        double std = 0;
        double mean = 0;
        DA.GetData<int>("Seed", ref seed);
        DA.GetData<double>("StdDev", ref std);
        DA.GetData<double>("Mean", ref mean);
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        double u1 = 1.0 - rand.NextDouble();
        double u2 = 1.0 - rand.NextDouble();
        double randStdNormal = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u1)) * Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * u2);
        double randNormal = mean + std * randStdNormal;
        DA.SetData("Output", randNormal);
    }
```

Comment: Debugging didn't help you to find out which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: No, I am using Grasshopper for Rhino.  Do you know how to get the error trace to output into Grasshopper?

Also, I notice that my output to the module says "out" and not "output".  I am not sure why it isn't picking up my output parameter.

Comment: Just tried your code and it doesn't throw any errors.